# C# Bina com Usb Fax Modem

Tags: c#, winforms, porta-serial

Gostaria de saber uma forma de pegar o número do telefone de um fax modem usb, utilizando `C#`.

***Exemplo:*** Tenho um computador com um *fax modem usb* conectado a uma linha telefônica, quando alguém me ligar o meu sistema pega o numero que está meligando e coloca em `textbox`.

Estou tentando com `SerialPort` da seguinte forma:

```
public void GetNumber() {

    serialPort.PortName = cbPorta.Text;
    serialPort.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cbTxTransmissao.Text);
    serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    serialPort.Open();            
    var Comando= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("AT&Zn?");
    serialPort.WriteLine(Comando);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
   lbStatus.Text = serialPort.ReadLine();
   serialPort.Close();
}
```

Comment: Quase sempre os faxmodems trabalham apenas com FSK para identificação de chamadas, e no Brasil usa-se o DTMF. Se o faxmodem não der suporte a DTMF, não há o que fazer (um adaptador DTMF pra FSK usualmente é mais caro que um identificador separado).